# How to Search and Navigate XML Nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have the following XML :

```
<LOCALCELL_V18 ID = "0x2d100000">
  <MXPWR ID = "0x3d1003a0">100</MXPWR> 
</LOCALCELL_V18>
<LOCALCELL_V18 ID = "0x2d140000">
  <MXPWR ID = "0x3d1403a0">200</MXPWR>  
</LOCALCELL_V18>
<LOCALCELL_V18 ID = "0x2d180000">  
  <MXPWR ID = "0x3d1803a0">300</MXPWR>   
</LOCALCELL_V18>
```

I want to get the inner text of each `<MXPWR>`.  however, it is not allowed to use ID#　to locate the inner text since it is not always the same. here is my code:

```
XmlNodeList LocalCell = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("LOCALCELL_V18");

foreach (XmlNode LocalCell_Children in LocalCell)
{
    XmlElement MXPWR = (XmlElement)LocalCell_Children;
    XmlNodeList MXPWR_List = MXPWR.GetElementsByTagName("MXPWR");
    for (int i = 0; i < MXPWR_List.Count; i++)
    {
       MaxPwr_form_str = MXPWR_List[i].InnerText;
    }
}
```

Any opinion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

I would use [xpath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). It was designed for just this sort of problem. Something like:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
....
string fileName = "data.xml"; // your file here
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(fileName);
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

// Compile an xpath expression
XPathExpression expr = nav.Compile("./LOCALCELL_V18/MXPWR");
XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(expr);

// Iterate on the node set
while (iterator.MoveNext())
{
    string s = iterator.Current.Value;
}
```

When I run this on your XML file (wrapped in a root node) I get:

```
s = 100
s = 200
s = 300
```

Answer (score 7):

I would use XLinq:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

var xDoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");

var mxpwrs = xDoc.Descendants("MXPWR");
foreach (var mxpwr in mxpwrs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mxpwr.Value);
}
```

Comment: Perfect use for Linq to eliminate the need for Xpath.